# Does jetty has "Servlet Pluggability Mechanism" feature for servlet 3.0?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jetty-9

I choose jetty stack as webserver run servlet for my project.
Now I try to add Jax-rs implement with jersey, find that "Servlet Pluggability Mechanism" is not working, and not mentioned in jetty's document.

in jersey's document: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.servlet.3

> 4.7.2.3. Servlet Pluggability Mechanism
>
> Servlet framework pluggability mechanism is a feature introduced with Servlet 3.0 specification. It simplifies the configuration of various frameworks built on top of Servlets. Instead of having one web.xml file working as a central point for all the configuration options, it is possible to modularize the deployment descriptor by using the concept of so-called web fragments - several specific and focused web.xml files. A set of web fragments basically builds up the final deployment descriptor. This mechanism also provides SPI hooks that enable web frameworks to register themselves in the Servlet container or customize the Servlet container deployment process in some other way. This section describes how JAX-RS and Jersey leverage the Servlet pluggability mechanism.

With that mechanism enable, you can omitted the explict `servlet-class` tag declare.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    ...
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.foo.rest.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

which I find not working in jetty 9 current snapshot version(jetty 9 support servlet 3.1 spec). Did jetty has the feature?

If it has, What step or config or document I got missing?
If it hasn't, How to achieve this?

Comment: In order to answer this, you'll need to be far more specific on your setup and configuration.  There's lots in play, your web.xml, its version, any fragments, your `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` configurations, your annotations, the resolved descriptor load orders (stupidly complex part of the spec), etc.  (As of today, the only part of the servlet spec that Jetty doesn't support is `HttpServletRequest.upgrade()`)

Answer (score 0):

**Servlet Pluggability Mechanism is there in jetty.**

And this is a silly question that I'd missing the "jersey-container-servlet" which shoud add to the POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```